# Formatar número de 3200 para 3.200 com PHP

Tags: php, number-format

Tenho que transformar valores como:

```
3200
5000
10000
13000
100000
```

em

```
3.200
5.000
10.000
13.00
100.000
```

Tentei usar a função `number_format`do `PHP`mas não consegui fazer corretamente. Como posso resolver esse problema ?

Comment: Como você tentou?

Comment: `number_format($variavel, 2, '.', '.');`

Comment: e qual o seu retorno ?

Comment: number_format ($variavel, 0 , ' , ' ,  '.');

Comment: 3.200.00 com .00 dps e não quero isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode elaborar da seguinte forma:

```
function formata_valor($valor){
    if($valor!=NULL){
        echo number_format($valor, 0, ',', '.');
    } else {
        echo "Nenhum valor foi preenchido.";
    }
}
echo formata_valor("10000"); // output 10.000
```

> Documentação de referência: http://php.net/number_format

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado.

Comment: Por nada Alisson, a disposição!

Comment: Fica a sugestão de explicar o que faz cada parâmetro pra valorizar a resposta. Nem todo mundo lê os links recomendados. Na verdade nem todo mundo lê as respostas com atenção :)

Comment: Tranquilo, eu coloquei a documentação como referência também... Mas como respondi rapidinho, acabei por não completando muito a explicação. Mas agradeço seu toque! :)

Comment: Se completar, fica até mais fácil de usarmos para fechar futuras duplicatas com a mesma dúvida (e atrai mais votinhos de "brinde") :)

Comment: Ok, farei uma explicação melhor ;)